# Java Pattern New Line Problem

Tags: java, regex

In reading the documentation for `Pattern`, it declares `\s` as a whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`.  So why does the second scanner below return `null`, and how can I get the pattern to work with the new line character?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String pattern = "\\s*a";

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner("    \t a");
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner("  \t\n a");

        System.out.println(scanner1.findInLine(pattern));
        System.out.println(scanner2.findInLine(pattern));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
         a
null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`findInLine` stops when it encounters a line break (as the name suggests):

```
"  \t\n a"
 ^^^^
   |  
   +-- this is where findInLine(...) searches for the pattern: `\s*a`
```

You should use [`findWithinHorizon(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) instead:

```
String pattern = "\\s*a";
Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner("    \t a");
Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner("  \t\n a");
System.out.printf(">%s<\n\n", scanner1.findInLine(pattern));
System.out.printf(">%s<", scanner2.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0));
```

will print:

```
>        a<

>   
 a<
```

Comment: Of course you're right.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks.